# Linked list incorrect reading & error message

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to read a textfile, put the information from that textfile into a linked list, close the file and then print everything into my program using the linked list.
For some reason i get "-858993460" after my first row for the rest list till i hit my 15 line then i get an error:

> Exception thrown at 0x5313B5F2 (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication14.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

The list I'm reading from:

```
TERMINATOR T-800 1

TERMINATOR T-1000 2

TERMINATOR T-800 3

TERMINATOR T-800 4

TERMINATOR T-1000 5

TERMINATOR T-800 6

TERMINATOR T-800 7

TERMINATOR T-800 8

TERMINATOR T-1000 9

TERMINATOR T-800 10

TORMONUTTUR T-800 101

TERMINATOR T-800 11

FEL FEL FEL

TERMINATOR T-1000 12

TERMINATOR T-800 13

TERMINATOR T-800 14

TERMINATOR           T-800         15

       TERMINATOR T-1000 16

TERMINATOR T-800 17                       

TERMINATOR T-800 18

TERMINATOR T-1000 19

TERMINATOR T-800 20
```

Can someone please explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Link {
char robot[15];
char terminatortyp[10];
int idnr;
struct Link *next;
};
struct Link *first = NULL;

int main(void) {
int antal = 0;
struct Link a;
FILE *tsin = fopen("textfil1R.txt", "r");
if (tsin == NULL) {
    printf("Kunde inte läsa filen 'textfil.txt'.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

struct Link *temp;
while (fgets(a.robot, sizeof a.robot, tsin) != NULL && fgets(a.terminatortyp, sizeof a.terminatortyp, tsin) != NULL && fscanf(tsin, "%d", &a.idnr) != EOF)
{
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Link));
    *temp->robot = a.robot;
    *temp->terminatortyp = a.terminatortyp;
    temp->idnr = a.idnr;
    temp->next = first;
    first = temp;

    ++antal;
}
fclose(tsin);

struct node *p; 
p = first; 
while (p != NULL)
{
    printf("%s", a.robot);
    printf("%s", a.terminatortyp);
    printf("%d", a.idnr);
    temp = temp->next;
}

printf("%d", antal);
getch();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Don't mix `fgets` with `fscanf`. Break that complicated `while` into smaller parts. Start with a single `fgets` of each input line and examine it further - you cannot sensibly apply two `fgets` calls to the same input line. You are trying to limit the input length read, but the second fields are not all the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

One problem is you mixed fgets and fscanf. fgets reads **a given length** regardless of what is read (assume no EOF is received).So in the 1st loop, when you call `fgets(a.robot, sizeof a.robot, tsin)`, it reads 15 bytes and saves `TERMINATOR T-80` into `a.robot`, and when you call fgets again, it reads another 10 bytes and saves `0 1\r\nTERMI` into `a.type`. Now the following `fscanf` fails because the next coming character is `N`, which does not fit `%d`.

Another problem is you're appointing arrays like pointers, that's the reason for the error generated. (Bad compiler for not finding this issue for you). `a.robot` is of type `char [15]`, and when you assign `*temp->robot = a.robot`, **you are attempting to assign a `char [15]` to a `char`** (`*temp-robot` is essentially the same as `temp->robot[0]`). The same applies to the next line. You should use `strcpy` (or safer, `strncpy`) instead.

And after closing read file descriptor, what is `struct node`??? And how can you print `a.xxx` while looping with condition `p != NULL`??? With assigning **`temp = temp->next`** each loop???